# Is it possible to {activate|de-activate} SIGFPE generation only for some specific C++11 code segments?

Tags: linux, c++11, exception, floating-point, ieee-754

I am writing a path tracer in C++11, on Linux, for the numerical simulation of light transport and I am using

```
#include <fenv.h>
...
feenableexcept( FE_INVALID   | 
                FE_DIVBYZERO | 
                FE_OVERFLOW  | 
                FE_UNDERFLOW );
```

in order to catch and debug any numerical errors that may eventually occur during execution.

At some point in the code I have to compute the intersection of rays (line segments) against axis-aligned bounding boxes (AABBs). For this computation I am using a very optimized and robust [ray-box intersection algorithm](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~awilliam/box/) which relies on the generation of some special values (e.g. NaN and inf) described in the IEEE 754 standard. Obviously, I am not interested in catching floating point exceptions generated specifically by this ray-box intersection routine.

Thus, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to deactivate the generation of floating point exception signals (SIGFPE) for only some sections of the code (i.e. for the ray-box intersection code section)?
2. When we are calculating simulations we are very concerned about
   performance. In the case that it is possible to suppress exception
   signals only for specific code sections, can this be done at
   compile time (i.e. instrumenting/de-instrumenting code during its
   generation, such that we could avoid expensive function calls)?

Thank you for any help!

**UPDATE**

It is possible to instrument/deinstrument code through the use of `feenableexcept` and `fedisableexcept` function calls (actually, I posted this question because I was not aware about the `fedisableexcept`, only `feenableexcept`... shame on me!). For instance:

```
#include <fenv.h>

int main() {
    float a = 1.0f;

    fedisableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO);   // disable div by zero catching

    // generates an inf that **won't be** catched
    float c = a / 0.0f;

    feenableexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO);   // enable div by zero catching

    // generates an inf that **will be** catched
    float d = a / 2.0f;

    return 0
}
```

Comment: Do you want floating-point trapping turned on in the other code? Floating-point trapping is commonly disabled by default, in which case it is already off for your path-tracing code, and there is no need to turn it on for the other code unless you specifically want floating-point trapping in the other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard C++ does not provide any way to mark code at compile-time as to whether it should run with floating-point trapping enabled or disabled. In fact, support for manipulating the floating-point environment is not required by the standard, so whether an implementation has it at all is implementation-dependent. Any answer beyond standard C++ depends on the particular hardware and software you are using, but you have not reported that information.

On typical processors, enabling and disabling floating-point trapping is achieved by changing a processor control register. You do not need a function call to do this, but it is not the function call that is expensive, as you suggest in your question. The actual instruction may consume time as it may require the processor to serialize instruction execution. (Modern processors may have hundreds of instructions executing at the same time—some being decoded, some waiting for a subunit within the processor, some in various stages of calculation, some waiting to write their results to general registers, and so on. When changing a control register, the processor may have to wait for all currently executing instructions to finish, then change the register, then start executing new instructions.) If your hardware behaves this way, there is no way to get around it. (With such hardware, which is common, it is not possible to compile code to run with or without trapping without actually executing the run-time instruction to change the control register.)

You might be able to mitigate the time cost by batching path-tracing calculations, so they are performed in groups with only two changes to the floating-point control register (one to turn traps off, one to turn them on) for the entire group.

Comment: @ChristianPagot: Processors have instructions such as Intel’s “LDMXCSR” and “STMXCSR” to load and store control registers. You generally do not access these directly; the feenableexcept routine does it for you. If you do access them directly, you need to use special features of the compiler (such as GCC’s “asm”) to insert assembly code or to use assembly language source files, and you need particular knowledge of your compiler and operating system so that you can do this in a way they support (or at least tolerate). There is generally no point in it; you can just call feenableexcept.

Comment: @ChristianPagot: Ultimately, the point is that the actual function call to feenableexcept is not expensive—the execution time for the instructions that implement the function call is small. It is the change of the processor state that is expensive, and you cannot avoid changing the processor state when you change the floating-pont trap setting.

Comment: @ChristianPagot and Eric: ISO C and C++ have `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`  which you're supposed to use to make code-gen respect the fact that the FP environment might not be the default, and that `fesetenv()` or `feenableexcept()` might be used *between* different statements in the same function, so `x+y` can't necessarily CSE with another `x+y` for example, if they might have been done with a different rounding mode.  Or if raising exceptions twice is a visible side-effect.  But see 
 [pragma STDC FENV\_ACCESS ON is not supported](//stackoverflow.com/q/33471254)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv says  *The floating-point environment access and modification is only meaningful when `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` is supported and is set to ON.* ... *In practice, few current compilers, such as HP aCC, Oracle Studio, or IBM XL, support the #pragma explicitly, but most compilers allow meaningful access to the floating-point environment anyway.*

Comment: Some modern x86 CPUs may rename the FP environment, allowing you to change it without serializing.  I read somewhere that Intel since Core2 at least renames the x87 control register.  I didn't go looking for MXCSR (which is presumably needed less often, because there are specific instructions for conversion to integer with truncation (C cast semantics) or rounding with the current rounding mode.  Unlike x87 before SSE3 where `int i = (int)fp;` required changing the rounding mode to truncation and back).  But yes, CPUs have to preserve the illusion of `ldmxcsr` running in program order.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disabling floating point exceptions can be realized with:

```
#include <fenv.h>

fenv_t env;
feholdexcept(&env);

//
// TODO: code that needs FPE suppressed comes here
//

fesetenv(&env);
```

In this way, the floating point environment is saved while disabling FPE with `feholdexcept` and restored with `fesetenv`.